# Using async/await syntax with Twisted callbacks

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I'd like to use `async/await` syntax with Twisted [Deferred.addCallback](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/17.5.0/core/howto/defer.html#basic-callback-functions) method. But as stated in the documentation, `addCallback` callback is called synchronously. I've seen [inlineCallbacks](https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/howto/defer-intro.html#inline-callbacks-using-yield) decorator used for this purpose, but I'd prefer using `async/await` syntax (if it's even possible, or meaningful).

I picked up the original code from [pika documentation](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/twisted_example.html), but I had no luck trying to migrate it to async/await syntax:

```
import pika
from pika import exceptions
from pika.adapters import twisted_connection
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor, protocol, task


async def run_async(connection):
    channel = await connection.channel()
    exchange = await channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic_link',type='topic')
    queue = await channel.queue_declare(queue='hello', auto_delete=False, exclusive=False)
    await channel.queue_bind(exchange='topic_link', queue='hello', routing_key='hello.world')
    await channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    queue_object, consumer_tag = await channel.basic_consume(queue='hello', no_ack=False)
    l = task.LoopingCall(read_async, queue_object)
    l.start(0.01)


async def read_async(queue_object):
    ch,method,properties,body = await queue_object.get()
    if body:
        print(body)
    await ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters()
cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, twisted_connection.TwistedProtocolConnection, parameters)
d = cc.connectTCP('rabbitmq', 5672)
d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
d.addCallback(run_async)
reactor.run()
```

This obviously does not work because nobody awaits `run_async` function.

Comment: [`ensureDeferred`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html#coroutines-with-async-await) is what you want to use

Comment: @notorious.no I already tried to wrap `cc.connectTCP('rabbitmq', 5672)` with `defer.ensureDeferred`, but it did not help. Was that what you meant? Thanks.

Comment: @notorious.no got it. I have to wrap the callback itself with ensureDeferred. I was wrapping the result of the callback which obvisously doesn't make it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out by *notorious.no* and by Twisted documentation, [`ensureDeferred`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html#coroutines-with-async-await) is the way to go. Still, you have to wrap the callback result and not the callback itself which wasn't clear to me.

This is how it looks eventually:

```
def ensure_deferred(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return defer.ensureDeferred(result)
    return wrapper


@ensure_deferred
async def run(connection):
    channel = await connection.channel()
    exchange = await channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic_link', type='topic')
    queue = await channel.queue_declare(queue='hello', auto_delete=False, exclusive=False)
    await channel.queue_bind(exchange='topic_link', queue='hello', routing_key='hello.world')
    await channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    queue_object, consumer_tag = await channel.basic_consume(queue='hello', no_ack=False)
    l = task.LoopingCall(read, queue_object)
    l.start(0.01)


@ensure_deferred
async def read(queue_object):
    ch, method, properties, body = await queue_object.get()
    if body:
        print(body)
    await ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters()
cc = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, twisted_connection.TwistedProtocolConnection, parameters)
d = cc.connectTCP('rabbitmq', 5672)
d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
d.addCallback(run)
reactor.run()
```

Thanks.