# how to sleep in twisted LoopingCall

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I have a `work()` method that calls functions that may invoke `time.sleep`. This clearly goes against recommended twisted usage.

Suppose one could replace LoopingCall with `threads.deferToThread()` and loop manually in our worker, but are there alternative ways to accomplish this while still utilizing LoopingCall?

Pseudocode:

```py
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

looping_call = LoopingCall(work)
looping_call.start(10)


def work():
    result = False
    for i in elements:
        if blocking_function(i):  # note processing sequentially here is preferred
            result = True

    if result:
        dosomething()


def blocking_function(i):
    time.sleep(5)
    return True  # or False
```

related: [A non blocking way to sleep/wait in twisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729079/a-non-blocking-way-to-sleep-wait-in-twisted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `deferToThread` only for the blocking call:

```
async def work():
    result = False
    for i in elements:
        # note processing sequentially here is preferred
        if await deferToThread(lambda: blocking_function(i)):  
            result = True

    if result:
        dosomething()
```

Comment: `async` functions may be passed to LoopingCall as-is?

Comment: Yep, at least in a sufficiently recent version of Twisted.

Comment: This does not quite work -- for see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44627140/1803648 for answer that works.

Comment: It will work if you have a sufficiently recent version of Twisted.  If you have an older version - yes, you will have to adapt from coroutine to Deferred yourself, perhaps using `ensureDeferred` (or, better, `Deferred.fromCoroutine`).